# How to solve cryptic dpkg error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, dpkg

I get this message when my ubuntu system was crashed.

> dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

How to solve it?

Comment: Following the instructions in the message might help..."manually run" means run in a terminal (Applications>Accessories>Terminal).

Comment: ohh, I did it but this message is always there. that's why I asked the question here :-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

(in english, as a super user, configure all the debian packages.)

Comment: this command does not help in this case, the message is just the same :-s

Comment: Hmmm... That's not normal!